Google OAuth redirect_uri_mismatch when trying to launch localhost server from Flask app after using Pyinstaller
I have created a web app using Flask in Python, which I successfully linked to Google's OAuth system (or so I thought). When I run the app directly with Python from the command line on http://localhost:5000 I have no problems loading the page and the authentication flow is successful.
I wanted to package the app into an executable that will set up and run the localhost on a machine, and used Pyinstaller to do so. However, when running the executable, my OAuth flow somehow breaks and I can't figure out why. I get this error.
In the app itself, I run:
webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000/')
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True) I

I'm pretty new to this, so I don't understand why the app is not running on the port as specified, but rather on a random port that changes every time. In the console, I have already made sure that the redirect uri and javascript origins are set correctly (as I was already able to run everything manually), so the problem arises specifically from the pyinstaller build.
Please let me know if there is anything else I should specify, and thanks for the help in advance!
